# Why does the Riemann Xi function $(\xi(s))$ have order of growth 1

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

Why does $s(s-1)\xi(s)$, have order of growth 1?

In other words, why is it that $\forall \epsilon > 0 $ $\exists A_{\epsilon},B_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb R_+$ so that $\forall s \in \mathbb C$, $(s)(s-1)\xi(s) \le A_{\epsilon}exp^{B_{\epsilon}|s|^{1+\epsilon}}$

Recall that $\xi(s)$ is defined by the functional equation: 
$$
                          s(s-1)\zeta(s) = \frac{s(s-1)*\xi(s)*\pi^{s/2}}{\Gamma(s/2)} \tag{*}
$$

$$$$
Note also that if I can figure out why $\xi(s)$ has order of growth 1, then I can quickly determine that
$$
                          |(s-1)\zeta(s)| \leq A_{\epsilon} \; \exp \left(a_{\epsilon}|s|^{1+\epsilon} \right) \tag{**}
$$
because I can show that  $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s/2)}$, $(s-1)$, and $\pi^{s/2}$ each have of order of growth 1.  Hence, I can plug in their growth orders into (*) and deduce (**).

Comment: $\xi(s)$ has poles at $s=0,1$, so how can it be bounded around there?

Comment: @blue Maybe I need s(s-1)ξ(s).  I'll have to think about this a little bit more.

Comment: One has to be careful about ambiguity in the symbols. The original xi function of Riemann is different from the Landau Riemann xi function. The first has poles at 0 and 1. The second is an entire function.